# Cannot draw thin line in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, line

I followed a tutorial to create a canvas graph using js. The code plotting is this:

```
function plotData(context, dataSet, sections, xScale) {
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.outlineWidth = 0;
    context.strokeWidth = 0;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, dataSet[0]);
    for (i=0; i<sections; i++) {
        context.lineTo(i * xScale, dataSet[i]);
    }
    context.stroke();
}
```

I am calling this function with an array holding the points where to go.. The x value is calculated per column  (xScale) and the resulting graph if i use more than 1 source of data shows up fine. Screenshot when working fine:

http://s21.postimg.org/vlc1qg9iv/Screen_Shot_2016_04_08_at_15_48_42.png

But when i remove the 2 last data lines and leave only 1 line (so when the graph has a smaller difference between graph max and min values it shows up like this:

http://s16.postimg.org/ex0fakef9/Screen_Shot_2016_04_08_at_15_44_21.png

It is in this screenshot that you can clearly see, that while it should draw a line, the line is not really a 1px line but a shape, much like a (badly) distorted line?

I am not sure if i am doing something wrong or i am plainly ignoring something? The height of the canvas is fixed and it is always calculated using:

```
canvas = $('#canvas-container canvas')[0];
canvas.width = $('#canvas-container').width() * 0.9;
canvas.height = $('#canvas-container').width() / 1.45;
```

Thanks!

Codepen of the exact effect (from the exact tutorial) can be found here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXMwBy?editors=1111

(notice there are 2 more lines of graph data i commented out and in doing so i made the Val_max and Val_min vars different to "stretch" the data in the Y line)

Comment: Don't use CSS to scale the canvas. Instead, scale the canvas element directly: `canvasElement.width=something; canvasElement.height=something;`

Comment: I hoped it would be something like this. However, my code looks like it is editing the canvas element and not its css? Unless i am completely confused :) (edited my code to show that)

Comment: The other thing to consider is that both screenshots look identical, except the line... if it was just a matter of stretching all the pixels, wouldn't the rest of the graphic be affected too?

Comment: Yes, I notice that disparity also, Ok, I'll reopen the question with the understanding that you will provide a minimal (misbehaving) example for us to work with. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I added a codepen link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stretching the Y axis on every operation after this line:

```
context.scale(1,-1 * yScale);
```

Instead, remove the line above and multiply the y values when you draw the line in `plotData()`.

```
// multiply all Y values by -yScale to flip and scale
context.moveTo(0, dataSet[0] * -yScale);
for (i=1;i<sections;i++) {
    context.lineTo(i * xScale, dataSet[i] * -yScale);
}
```